# . Tengo un problema con Java q no entiendo.. AYUDENME PORFA

Tags: java

**Hola, programador. Tengo un problema con el lenguaje Java...**

[//Captura de pantalla del codigo en vscode...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jycok.jpg)

Lo que **intentaba hacer** era un **bitmap 5x5** y luego de crear ese bitmap intentar **imprimirlo** en la pantalla. Creo que el error se debe a que un "int [][]" no se puede tratar como un simple "int"... ciertamente no tiene mucho  sentido mi inferencia, pero ayudenme, no soy nuevo en programacion y ahora voy a aprender java y es mi primer proyecto (aclaro).

Aqui esta mi sintaxis erronea.

```
class juego1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int mapa = new int [5][5];

        

        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

            for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
                
                mapa[i][j] = 1;

            }

        for( int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {

            for( int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {

                System.out.print(mapa[k][l]);
            
            }
    
            System.out.println("");

        }

        }


    }
}
```

Estare muy agradecido quien me ayude... de verdad.. muy agradecido <3 :')

no intente nada, no tengo ni idea cual seria la solucion....

Comment: Pues para tantos lenguajes que sabes perfectamente no deberías tener problema con algo tan básico.

Comment: Por favor, no pongas capturas de pantalla y menos en un link externo que mañana podría estar roto. Incluye el mensaje de error como parte de tu pregunta. El IDE te dice incluso en qué línea está el error. Esa información es valiosa. Lee [ask]. Y no digas que sabes _perfectamente_ c, c++ o c#. Con que lograras aprobar el curso más básico de cualquiera de estos lenguajes no tendrías el problema que dices. Acá somos programadores y no vale fanfarronear con algo así en ninguna pregunta, menos si es tan básica.

Answer (score 5):

Además de ser básico, el mismo VSCode te lo está diciendo, no podés convertir un int[][] a int y viceversa.
En todo caso sería:

```
int[][] mapa = new int[5][5];
```

Y no:

```
int mapa = new int[5][5];
```

Porque ni siquiera estás declarando el array.

Comment: Bienvenido y gracias por la respuesta. Resulta un tanto complicado responder preguntas que no están bien formadas, pero si que se valora tu aporte. Dejaste el código en _snippets_, que están diseñados para HTML/CSS/Javascript que se ejecutan directamente en el navegador. No es el caso de java y ningún otro lenguaje. Por favor no los uses para otra cosa fuera de lo que está soportado. Puedes ver el historial de ediciones haciendo clic en la etiqueta _editada a las_ o _editada hace_  para ver los cambios realizados o directamente darle en [edit] para observar cómo ha quedado.

Comment: El principal problema de la pregunta es que el mensaje de error está en un recurso externo que no es visible más que haciendo clic en el vínculo y que mañana podría estar roto. Por otro lado, se pide que la información de errores y código quede en texto y no en imágenes, por muchas razones. Te invito a leer [answer] y [ask]. Encontrarás mucha más información sobre preguntas que no se consideran de buena calidad también en [¿por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/21) en [meta].

Comment: Una disculpa por tanto texto y de nuevo bienvenido!